# How to render a CALayer with a different blending mode, like screen or multiply?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-animation

I have a `UIImageView` and want it to be displayed with a specific blend mode. I know the iPhone has different blend modes, and it's probably possible to do it with a lot of CG code… but maybe there's a nice way with the `CALayer` of `UIImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see here: [composite colors: CALayer and blend mode on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658751/composite-colors-calayer-and-blend-mode-on-iphone/3241164#3241164)

Answer (score 7):

Set the *compositingFilter* of a view's layer to a supported blend mode string. From the docs, a layer's *compositingFilter* is

> A CoreImage filter used to composite the layer and the content behind it.

To obtain a list of Core Image filters, print out the filter names defined by a kCICategoryCompositeOperation

```
[CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryCompositeOperation]
```

or directly as

```
[CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:@"CICategoryCompositeOperation"]
```

The array will include Core Image filters in the form

```
{
   CIColorBlendMode,
   CIColorBurnBlendMode,
   CIColorDodgeBlendMode,
   CIMultiplyBlendMode,
   ...
}
```

To use the CIMultiplyBlendMode, set "multiplyBlendMode" as the compositingFilter on the layer

```
self.layer.compositingFilter = @"multiplyBlendMode";
```

Comment: Complete list of filters is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000136-SW71).

Comment: Since the question is about iOS, beware, though, that Apple states in the documentation for `compositingFilter`: "This property is not supported on layers in iOS."

Comment: Strange that the documentation says that it's not supported on iOS, but it does appear to work as shown by this sample project: https://github.com/arthurschiller/CompositingFilters

Comment: This definitely works. I was able to recreate this from the github project listed above. I think the key factor that make this work is the hierarchy of the views: the subview is the one that needs the `compositingFilter`, not the parent view.

Comment: Did you set the imageView layer?