# CIGaussianBlur Quality: Banding & Artifacts

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, gaussian, cifilter

I am trying to blur the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer on applicationWillResignActive just as in the stock iOS Camera App.

Since rasterizing **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer** and blurring itself produces an empty frame, I approached it by keeping a **CIImage** from **didOutputSampleBuffer** and upon **applicationWillResignActive**, I take the **CIImage** -> Apply **CIFilter** **CIGaussianBlur** to it, add a **UIImageView** to **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer** and make that **UIImageView's** Image to be the **UIImage** version of the blur I applied the **CIGaussianBlur** to.

This seem to be working okay so far... However, it seem to produce quite a bit of banding, displaying quality issues on the Gaussian Blur.

[image]

### Grabbing the Frame:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

            let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
            CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))

            let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer!)

            let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer!)
            let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer!)
            let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer!)

            let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

            let bitmap = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue|CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
            let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmap.rawValue)
            let quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context!)
            CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer!,CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))

            self.cameraBufferImage = CIImage(CGImage: quartzImage!)
}
```

### Applying the CIGaussianBlur:

```
func blurPreviewWindow() {
    let previewLayer = self.previewView.layer as? AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    previewLayer?.connection.enabled = false

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let inputImage = self.cameraBufferImage!.imageByApplyingOrientation(6)

    let clampFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIAffineClamp")
    clampFilter!.setDefaults()
    clampFilter!.setValue(inputImage, forKey: "inputImage")

    if let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") {
        currentFilter.setValue(clampFilter!.outputImage, forKey: "inputImage")
        currentFilter.setValue(50.0, forKey: "inputRadius")

        if let output = currentFilter.outputImage {
            if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, fromRect: inputImage.extent) {
                let processedImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)
                self.previewBlurImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.previewView.bounds)
                self.previewBlurImageView?.alpha = 0
                self.previewView.addSubview(self.previewBlurImageView!)
                self.previewBlurImageView?.image = processedImage
                self.previewBlurImageView?.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
                self.previewBlurImageView?.layer.filters = [currentFilter]

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: [.BeginFromCurrentState], animations: {
                                                () -> Void in
                    self.previewBlurImageView?.alpha = 1
                }, completion: { _ in })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

May be there's a whole different approach to this of this iOS 10 era?

### UPDATE:

Could this be a colorspace issue? Since the test device is iPhone 7, which has wide color?

Comment: Try using a different CIfilter related to blur("CIBoxBlur", "CIDiscBlur", "CiGaussianBlur", "CIMaskedVariableBlur" "CIMedianFilter","CIMotionBlur", "CIZoomBlur",)  you don't need to change any of your code .Just change the cifilter name.see that makes any difference....

Comment: It seems that other filters do the same, tho some less than others.  The most important part is, only CIGaussianBlur gives the look I am looking for.  May be it's the way I am extracting the CIImage?  May be there's a complete different approach to blurring AVCapturePreviewLayer?

Comment: If you want you can create your own custom filter check out the following link https://github.com/FlexMonkey/Filterpedia , http://flexmonkey.blogspot.com.au/2016/04/creating-custom-variable-blur-filter-in.html?m=1 , https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html hope this help....

Comment: Since above method is somewhat expensive, there HAS TO BE A BETTER way to blur out the live camera preview.

Comment: Did you checkout the link

Comment: I am currently.  Above method grabs a full 12mp image (of whatever the camera sensor produces) and tries to apply the filter.  If the camera preview layer is in the size of the screen, this could be done in a better way that just a rasterized camera preview is blurred.  I just can't figure out that part..

Comment: Checkout the link and you have to build your own colorKernal to achieve a new custom filter.its a complex process but spending bit of time will do the job...

Comment: Thank you.  I will.  There are many camera apps that are doing this easily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378666/how-to-apply-filter-to-video-real-time-using-swift  this solve your problem. i strongly recommend you to goto flexmokey and study about creating custom filter. unique filter stands out more then the local filters...always keep in mind...cu

Comment: Still dealing with this issue.  Could this be a color profile issue? Since this banding is happening on iPhone 7.

Comment: Did you try changing inputRadius..

Comment: I did.  Banding is more apparent when the image is darker..

Comment: Try autoEnhance the inputImage  before you apply your filter

Comment: To the CIImage before applying the layers? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Try the following link http://www.hangge.com/blog/cache/detail_902.html  I dont thing its a good idea to use CIAffineClamp as a input filter(this filter only clamps the pixels at the edge of the transformed image, extending them outwards).So, its better to auto enhance the inputImage and pass it to blurFilter or you need study filter from CICategoryColorAdjustment & CICategoryColorEffect. i want you to consider filter related to image hue,alpha,saturation,exposure....

Comment: i wondering the screenshot you posted is actually from the simulator or iPhone....

Comment: iPhone.  Removing the Clamp Filter still produces banding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was CIContext.

Changed:

```
let context = CIContext(options: nil)
```

To:

```
let context = CIContext(options: [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                  kCIContextOutputColorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), 
                                  kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: false])
```

No more banding or artifacts!!!

Comment: I'm glad that works for you, but it might still be doing more work than you need. If you just want a "UI-style" blur, have you tried putting your capture preview layer inside a `UIVisualEffectView`?

Comment: I had this all this time. UIVisualEffectView looks a little muddy sometimes, compared to Gaussian Blur.

Comment: out of curiosity, do you know what the default working and output colour spaces were originally?

Comment: I don't. Toggling kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer had no effect on the blur.