# Blend a movie with UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I was wondering is there any possible way to blend a movie with an image ? for example to create something like this image :

[image]

I know it's possible to blend two images with `CGBlendMode` and its constants like `kCGBlendModeMultiply` , `kCGBlendModeScreen` ,and `kCGBlendModeOverlay` but how can I achieve this with a movie file and image file to blend together ?

Is it possible anyway ?

Comment: Maybe you can find something from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378666/how-to-apply-filter-to-video-real-time-using-swift

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp Thank you ! but that a real time filter is it possible to add with an imported video file ?