# Applying filter to real time camera preview - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, core-image, dispatch-queue

I'm trying to follow the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32381052/8422218 to create an app which uses the back facing camera and adds a filter, then displays it on the screen in real time

here is my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CameraFilter
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?

    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    @IBOutlet weak var filteredImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupCaptureSession()
        setupDevice()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupCorrectFramerate(currentCamera: currentCamera!) // will default to 30fps unless stated otherwise
        setupPreviewLayer()
        startRunningCaptureSession()
    }

    func setupCaptureSession() {
        // should support anything up to 1920x1080 res, incl. 240fps @ 720p
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
    }

    func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            }
            else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
        }

        currentCamera = backCamera
    }

    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
            photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func setupCorrectFramerate(currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice) {
        for vFormat in currentCamera.formats {
            //see available types
            //print("\(vFormat) \n")

            var ranges = vFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges as [AVFrameRateRange]
            let frameRates = ranges[0]

            do {
                //set to 240fps - available types are: 30, 60, 120 and 240 and custom
                // lower framerates cause major stuttering
                if frameRates.maxFrameRate == 240 {
                    try currentCamera.lockForConfiguration()
                    currentCamera.activeFormat = vFormat as AVCaptureDevice.Format
                    //for custom framerate set min max activeVideoFrameDuration to whatever you like, e.g. 1 and 180
                    currentCamera.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = frameRates.minFrameDuration
                    currentCamera.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = frameRates.maxFrameDuration
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Could not set active format")
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

    func setupPreviewLayer() {
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame

        //set preview in background, allows for elements to be placed in the foreground
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        let comicEffect = CIFilter(name: "CIComicEffect")

        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let cameraImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!)

        comicEffect!.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        //let filteredImage = UIImage(CIImage: comicEffect!.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!)
        let filteredImage = UIImage(ciImage: comicEffect!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!)

        print("made it here")


        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.filteredImage.image = filteredImage
        }
    }

    func startRunningCaptureSession() {
        captureSession.startRunning()
        backCamera?.unlockForConfiguration()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

My storyboard contains a UIImageView that's the size of the entire screen. When I run my application, I can only see the camera preview but not the filter applied to it. Where am I going wrong?

I also found the following repo which contains all of the relevant code I need to create the application. https://github.com/altitudelabs/iOSRealTimeFilterTutorial

It's written in Objective-C and is quite outdated but I had a go at converting that into Swift code with no success:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CameraFilter
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import GLKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    var videoPreviewView: GLKView?
    var ciContext: CIContext?
    var eaglContext: EAGLContext?
    var videoPreviewViewBounds = CGRect.zero
    var videoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var cameraPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        let window: UIView? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.window
        eaglContext = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)
        videoPreviewView = GLKView(frame: (window?.bounds)!, context: eaglContext!)
        videoPreviewView?.enableSetNeedsDisplay = false

        videoPreviewView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2)
        videoPreviewView?.frame = (window?.bounds)!

        videoPreviewView?.bindDrawable()

        videoPreviewViewBounds = CGRect.zero

        videoPreviewViewBounds.size.width = CGFloat(videoPreviewView!.drawableWidth)
        videoPreviewViewBounds.size.height = CGFloat(videoPreviewView!.drawableHeight)

        ciContext = CIContext(eaglContext: eaglContext!, options: [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()])

        setupDevice()

        setupCaptureSession()
        setupInputOutput()
        setupCorrectFramerate(currentCamera: currentCamera!)
        setupPreviewLayer()



    }

    func setupCaptureSession() {
        // should support anything up to 1920x1080 res, incl. 240fps @ 720p
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high
    }

    func setupPreviewLayer() {
        cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.frame

        //set preview in background, allows for elements to be placed in the foreground
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
    }

    func setupInputOutput() {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentCamera!)
            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

            let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String): kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

            let captureSessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "capture_session_queue")
            videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureSessionQueue)

            videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

            captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
            captureSession.beginConfiguration()
            captureSession.commitConfiguration()
            captureSession.startRunning()
                    print("here")

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        let imageBuffer: CVImageBuffer? = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let sourceImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer!, options: nil)
        let sourceExtent: CGRect = sourceImage.extent

        let comicEffect = CIFilter(name: "CIComicEffect")

        let filteredImage: CIImage? = comicEffect?.outputImage

        let sourceAspect: CGFloat = sourceExtent.size.width / sourceExtent.size.height
        let previewAspect: CGFloat = videoPreviewViewBounds.size.width / videoPreviewViewBounds.size.height
        // we want to maintain the aspect radio of the screen size, so we clip the video image
        var drawRect: CGRect = sourceExtent
        if sourceAspect > previewAspect {
            // use full height of the video image, and center crop the width
            drawRect.origin.x += (drawRect.size.width - drawRect.size.height * previewAspect) / 2.0
            drawRect.size.width = drawRect.size.height * previewAspect
        }
        else {
            // use full width of the video image, and center crop the height
            drawRect.origin.y += (drawRect.size.height - drawRect.size.width / previewAspect) / 2.0
            drawRect.size.height = drawRect.size.width / previewAspect
        }

        videoPreviewView?.bindDrawable()

        if eaglContext != EAGLContext.current() {
            EAGLContext.setCurrent(eaglContext)
        }

        glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
        // set the blend mode to "source over" so that CI will use that
        glEnable(GLenum(GL_BLEND))
        glBlendFunc(GLenum(GL_ONE), GLenum(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA))
        if (filteredImage != nil) {
            ciContext?.draw(filteredImage!, in: videoPreviewViewBounds, from: drawRect)
        }

        videoPreviewView?.display()
    }

    func setupDevice() {
        let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
        let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices

        for device in devices {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
                backCamera = device
            }
            else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
                frontCamera = device
            }
        }

        currentCamera = backCamera
    }

    func setupCorrectFramerate(currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice) {
        for vFormat in currentCamera.formats {
            //see available types
            //print("\(vFormat) \n")

            var ranges = vFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges as [AVFrameRateRange]
            let frameRates = ranges[0]

            do {
                //set to 240fps - available types are: 30, 60, 120 and 240 and custom
                // lower framerates cause major stuttering
                if frameRates.maxFrameRate == 240 {
                    try currentCamera.lockForConfiguration()
                    currentCamera.activeFormat = vFormat as AVCaptureDevice.Format
                    //for custom framerate set min max activeVideoFrameDuration to whatever you like, e.g. 1 and 180
                    currentCamera.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = frameRates.minFrameDuration
                    currentCamera.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = frameRates.maxFrameDuration
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Could not set active format")
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I just get a blank screen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code on top

You are using a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` but this is going to    transport pixels capture by the camera directly to the screen, skipping your image processing and `CIFilter` and is not necessary.

Your conformance to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` is out of date. `func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)` is now called `func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)`

Because you won't be using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` you'll need to ask for permission before you'll be able to start getting    pixels from the camera. This is typically done in `viewDidAppear(_:)`    Like:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video) != .authorized
    {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video, completionHandler:
        { (authorized) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                if authorized
                {
                    self.setupInputOutput()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Also, if you are supporting rotation you will also need to update the `AVCaptureConnection` on rotation in your `didOutput` callback.

After making these changes [(full source code)](https://gist.github.com/bgayman/6b27428ea48750e8306975c735bd517e) your code worked, producing an image like so:

[image: Screenshot]